# How to change image used for www.domain.com

Tags: url, image

How do I change the image for [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) ([www.affordablemallorca.com](http://www.affordablemallorca.com))?  I am not a coder and need simple instructions to avoid high fees associated with servicing this domain.  Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close this because it's way too unspecific. Please provide details on your setup, what you have tried and why it's not working.

Comment: That's a bummer.  I have been sharing our website url and the photo that shows up is NOT the one I want.  I have no idea how to change it.  I was looking for help here.  You are not helpful.

Comment: Hi @Memphis this site is generally for Craft developers to find solutions to their technical problems, rather than site owners. Because Craft is a bespoke "blank canvas" toolbox for developers, it's impossible to give you specific advice because no-one except your original developer (and ideally you) knows how your site works. Please visit https://craftcms.com/partners to find a knowledgable developer, or you can also post a job in the #jobs channel on Craft Discord: https://craftcms.com/discord or on https://www.workwithcraft.com

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Memphis usually assets url setup from their volume. firstly you have to check that in your volume you have use static url or dynamic variable? after that you can change your assets url according to volume setup. if static url then just use @web for current site. if you want 3rd party site images then put that site Url. you can also use your .env or general.config variable here.

[image: Assets with site Url]

[image: Assets with custom url]